# DS1338 i2c Read issue

Tags: linux, i2c

Hi I'm trying read the time from RTC-DS1338 with my linux Single Board Computer, but there is a problem with my code. I'm reading bad outputs with it.

I tried to read with `i2cget -y 0 0x68 0` it works. but my code does not.

Can anybody help me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define I2C_ADDR 0x68

int main (void) 
{

char value;
int fd;
unsigned char pData[10];
char i;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR)) < 0)
    {
            printf("Error: Couldn't open device! %d\n", fd);
            return 1;
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, I2C_ADDR) < 0)
    {
            printf("Error: Couldn't find device on address!\n");
            return 1;
    }   

    while (1) 
    {

        if (read(fd, &pData, 4) != 4)
        {
            perror("Read conversion");
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<4;i++) printf(" %02x ",(pData[i] & 0xFF));    
            printf("\n");
        }

        sleep(2);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Bad Output:

```
 00  b3  49  47
 4e  27  09  21
 24  81  29  00
 1a  20  02  10
 16  1e  1a  46
 1a  00  96  18
 45  82  03  e0
 24  40  88  1c
```

Good Data:

```
 00  05  08  00
 01  05  08  00
 02  05  08  00
 03  05  08  00
 04  05  08  00
 05  05  08  00
```

Comment: What does the good data look like?

Comment: I have added the good data output. seconds should increase meaningful

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem with the below code

```
if ((fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR)) < 0)
{
        printf("Error: Couldn't open device! %d\n", fd);
        return 1;
}

if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, I2C_ADDR) < 0)
{
        printf("Error: Couldn't find device on address!\n");
        return 1;
}

if (write(fd, wData, 1) != 1)
{
    perror("Write to register");
}

if (read(fd, rData, 64) != 64)
{
    perror("Read conversion");
}
else
{
    memcpy(Dat,rData,7);
}

close(fd);


return 0;
```

Comment: If you want this to be a useful answer, it'd be helpful to at least explain what you did differently and to have more of the code showing (the previous version didn't have `wData` and `rData`).  I'm guessing it's the `write()` call that really made things start working here?